# Convert captured packet data to html in C

Tags: html, c, http, capture, packet

I have captured a packet using libpcap and have the packet data in a char array. When I print it in hex and ascii the output is

```
 
    47 45 54 20 2f 62 72 6f  77 73 65 2f 64 69 63 74    GET /browse/dict
    69 6f 6e 61 72 79 3f 73  3d 74 20 48 54 54 50 2f    ionary?s=t HTTP/
    31 2e 31 0d 0a 48 6f 73  74 3a 20 77 77 77 2e 64    1.1..Host: www.d
    69 63 74 69 6f 6e 61 72  79 2e 63 6f 6d 0d 0a 55    ictionary.com..U
    73 65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e  74 3a 20 4d 6f 7a 69 6c    ser-Agent: Mozil
    .....
    ......
    41 31 25 32 43 31 30 31  25 33 41 31 25 32 43 32    A1%2C101%3A1%2C2
    25 33 41 31 25 32 43 31  30 32 25 33 41 31 25 32    %3A1%2C102%3A1%2
    43 31 30 33 25 33 41 31  25 32 43 33 25 33 41 31    C103%3A1%2C3%3A1
    ............
    .....
```

Now I want to convert above http request/response from captured packet to html tags. How can I do that?

Comment: please clarify what do you want to do ,do you want to write character of each code in html?

Comment: I want to search for a certain string in the converted html of packet data

Comment: This looks like a request packet and not a response. Very unlikely that it would have a html payload.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what output you want to generate from that packet.

Comment: I want to capture the response packet and get the packet payload and print the html of the website I visited